# Eggs and family

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Martha goes out, carrying some hard boiled eggs in a basket.

She meets her sister and gives her half of the eggs in her basket plus half an egg.

She meets her cousin and gives her half of the eggs remaining in her basket plus half an egg.

She meets her sister-in-law and gives her half of the eggs remaining in her basket plus half an egg.

She goes home with no more eggs.

How many eggs did she have to start with?

(There's no credit to be given, someone asked me that riddle long ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it only physically makes sense to give eggs in whole numbers,

> half the eggs in the basket plus half an egg

means that at each point there are an odd number of eggs in the basket.

Working backwards from when Martha arrives home:

When she has 1 egg, she gives 1 egg to her sister-in-law. $\frac{1}{2}(1)+\frac{1}{2}=1$
When she has 3 eggs, she gives 2 eggs to her cousin. $\frac{1}{2}(3)+\frac{1}{2}=2$
When she has 7 eggs, she gives 4 eggs to her sister. $\frac{1}{2}(7)+\frac{1}{2}=4$

Thus Martha had 7 eggs in her basket to begin.

Comment: Good job, you got it!

Comment: "it only physically makes sense to give eggs in whole numbers" why? They're boiled. But you don't need (or use) that anyway.